# opencart last product in category products - image

Tags: php, image, opencart, product

I creating e-store, and first of my problems is that, I don't know how to make last product like image to next page.

Look here: http://puoskis24.lt/index.php?route=product/category&path=63 and you can see that 15 product showing in list, how to make 16 (last product is 16 where blank area) product would be my picture?

Here is my code with products page (category.tpl):

```
<div class="product-list">

<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<div>

  <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
  <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="name" style="text-align:center;display: inline;"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><p><?php echo $product['name']; ?></p></a></div>
  <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
  <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
  <div class="price" style="text-align:center;display: inline;">
    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
    <?php echo $product['price'];?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
    <br />
    <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
  <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
    <div class="cart" style="display:none;">

    </div>
  <div class="wishlist"><!--<a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a>--></div>
<div class="compare"><!--<a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a>--></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And what if I choose to show 24 products instead of 15 on one page? Or 48? Then Your "last product" would be on next row as the 25th or 49th...

Answer (score 0):

Admin -> System -> settings -> 'edit' -> option -> first option:

> **Default Items Per Page (Catalog):** 
>   Determines how many catalog items
>   are shown per page (products, categories, etc)

:)